# How can I find equation of the tangent line for a curve given in polar form?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, homework

Basic calculus

Please tell me how to find the tangent at $θ=π/3$ in the form $y=ax+b$ of the curve represented by $r=(r-\cosθ)^2$.

Comment: Is this a question about how to use the software product Wolfram *Mathematica*?  (See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Perhaps math.stackexchange.com would be a more appropriate site.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  I will check out the site. So I couldn't solve and find  good code before this Question by Wolfram site because I am a beginner of the Mathematica. IF you know  the code, could you please tell me how to solve it in this time. Thank you.

Comment: For a start, it's `Cos[θ]` in Mathematica.  Then `Solve[r==(r-Cos[θ])^2, r]` will give you formulas for `r`.  Then apply the formula for $dy/dx$ in polar coordinates to get the slope $a$ (look up `D[]` in the docs for how to differentiate).  Then plug in the values for the coordinates of the point of tangency and solve for `b`.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you curve in polar coordinates is:

```
r0 = 1;
r[phi_] = (r0 - Cos[phi])^2;
```

The x/y coordinates are:

```
xy[phi_] = r[phi] {Cos[phi], Sin[phi]};
```

Now the derivate dy/dx is: dy/dphi (dx/dphi)^-1. At phi= Pi/3:

```
der = D[r[phi], phi] /. phi -> Pi/3
derx = der[[2]]/der[[1]]
```

And a picture:

```
ParametricPlot[xy[phi], {phi, 0, 1.2}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Point[xy[Pi/3]], 
   Line[{{0.05, y[0.05]}, {0.15, y[0.15]}}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a **implicit** polar coordinate equation,so it is not easy to handle.

```
reg1 = Region[
   ImplicitRegion[r == (r - Cos[θ])^2, {r, θ}], 
   BaseStyle -> Blue, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {r, θ}, 
   PlotLabel -> r == (r - Cos[θ])^2];
reg2 = Region[
   ImplicitRegion[
    TransformedField["Polar" -> "Cartesian", 
      r == (r - Cos[θ])^2, {r, θ} -> {x, y}] // 
     Evaluate, {x, y}], BaseStyle -> Red, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {x, y}];
GraphicsRow[{reg1, reg2}]
```

[image: LHS is the curve in (r,θ) coordinate and the RHS is the curves in the (x,y) coordinate]

At First we need to differential the implicit equation $r=(r-\cos\theta)^2$ in $(r,\theta)$ coordinate.

```
Dt[r == (r - Cos[θ])^2]
```

$$dr=2 (r-\cos (\theta )) (d\theta  \sin (\theta )+dr)$$

So we can get $dr :d\theta$

And then we differential the map $(r,\theta)\mapsto (x,y)$ with $x=r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta$

```
With[{x = r*Cos[θ], y = r*Sin[θ]}, {Dt[x], Dt[y]}]
```

$$\{dx,dy\}=\{\cos (\theta ) dr-r d\theta  \sin (\theta ),\sin (\theta ) dr+r d\theta  \cos (\theta )\}$$

Now we can combine all of the above to get $\mathrm{d}y : \mathrm{d}x$

That is

```
Divide @@ 
   With[{x = r*Cos[θ], y = r*Sin[θ]}, {Dt[x], 
     Dt[y]}] /. 
  First@Solve[Dt[r == (r - Cos[θ])^2], Dt[r]] // Simplify
```

$$\frac{2 \sin (\theta ) \left(\cos (2 \theta )-2 r^2+r+1\right)}{-\cos (3 \theta )+\left(4 r^2-2 r+1\right) \cos (\theta )-4 r}$$

When $\theta=\pi/3$,we get $r$ from the original equation.

```
r/.Solve[r == (r - Cos[θ])^2 /. θ -> π/3, r]
```

$$\left\{\frac{1}{2} \left(2-\sqrt{3}\right),\frac{1}{2} \left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)\right\}$$

Combine the above code:

```
(Divide @@ 
       With[{x = r*Cos[θ], y = r*Sin[θ]}, {Dt[x], 
         Dt[y]}] /. 
      First@Solve[Dt[r == (r - Cos[θ])^2], Dt[r]] // 
     Simplify) /. θ -> π/3 /. 
  Solve[r == (r - Cos[θ])^2 /. θ -> π/3, 
   r] // Simplify
```

The tangent `a` is
$$\left\{3 \sqrt{3}-4,4+3 \sqrt{3}\right\}$$